# What is an algo wheel and where can I find references?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, reference-request

The term "algo wheel" has been flying around for some time yet I have yet to find a consistent definition. It obviously has to do with making trading strategies more comparable, but where did the term first come up, what are different versions/solution providers and where is a good starting point? On top of it, has anybody first-hand experience with it, and what is your take?

Thank you

Comment: This SEC report has a quick description on Page 35 https://www.sec.gov/files/Algo_Trading_Report_2020.pdf

Comment: Why the name? A "wheel [of fortune]" is a device for choosing a number from $1$ to $N$. Here the "wheel" chooses (but by logic, not at random) an algorithmic venue among $N$ where to send an order for execution. It also monitor the quality of the resulting execution to  improve such decisions in the future.

Comment: @nbbo2: So, is it based on some kind of exploitation-vs-exploration algorithm?